# Applying function to column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe containing some Ids, here for example the "manufacturers_id". Below a portion of my dataframe

[image]

With an api request, I am able to get the Manufacturer from the Id. My function looks like below:

```
def get_manufacturer(m_id):
    url = "myapi/" + m_id + "?token=my_token"
    response = requests.get(url)
    manufacturer = json.loads(response.text)['name']
    return manufacturer
```

Used individually, I can retrieve manufacturer from an Id.

But now, I want to apply this function to the whole column of my dataframe.

```
df['manufacturers_id'] = df['manufacturers_id'].apply(get_manufacturer(df['manufacturers_id']))
```

But It give me an error: `str is not callable`. Or `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`, depending on my tries

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
df['manufacturers_id'] = df['manufacturers_id'].apply(get_manufacturer)
```

Since the `apply` function used after a `pandas Series` indicates that entering each observation value into the function given in `apply()`.

Comment: `lambda x : get_manufacturer(x)` is the same as `get_manufacturer`.

Comment: @timgeb Yes, it is.